# Quais as convenções de nomes na criação de base de dados, tabelas e colunas em mysql

Tags: mysql

Gostava de saber que tipo de convenções existem nos nomes atribuídos a base de dados, tabelas e colunas em `mysql`, é normalmente usado `camelCase` ou outro tipo de convenção?

Comment: O banco não te força nenhuma padronização.

Comment: @perdeu, sim eu sei, mas existe alguma convenção?

Comment: Geralmente quem impõe convenções são os frameworks, se está usando um siga a dela. Só evite usar palavras reservadas como nome de colunas/tabelas, como por exemplo `desc` para um campo `descricao`

Comment: cara, dê uma olhada na minha resposta, pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O MySQL não é Case sensitive no Windows, portanto independente do "case" da criação da tabela, você sempre poderá acessá-la por tabela1 ou TABELA1, o mesmo ocorre com as colunas.

O que não ocorre com o Linux, que é Case Sensitive.

Embora seja configurável (veja como em: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

O que eu sugiro é usar nomenclatura que seja ideal independente da plataforma (Windows ou Linux) e da configuração do MySQL:

Nomes de tabelas:

PEDIDO_DE_VENDA

PEDIDO_DE_VENDA_PRODUTO

CLIENTES_ENDERECOS

E para colunas:

PEDIDO_ID, NUM_ENDERECO, VALOR_UNITARIO