# Estrutura/Nomenclatura de Tabelas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelagem

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de permissão e tenho um universo de 9 tabelas, as quais formam a permissão final para o usuário utilizar os meus sistemas, porém, estou em dúvidas de como construir duas delas, a de permissões "herdadas" de Sistemas e Grupos, isso quer dizer que quando, por exemplo, o usuário é um *administrador*, ele tem as permissões de administrador e, **herda**, as permissões de *usuário* e *visitante*.

O que eu gostaria é de montar uma estrutura que seja fácil de identificar isso e, o mais importante, de manipular, portanto, seguem as tabelas:

A tabela de Sistemas*:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Systems](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

A tabela de Grupos*:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Groups](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

A tabela de Permissões Herdadas de Sistemas**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InheritingSystem](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[IdSystem] [int] NOT NULL,
[IdInheritedSystem] [int] NOT NULL,
```

A tabela de Permissões Herdadas de Grupos**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InheritingGroup](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[IdGroup] [int] NOT NULL,
[IdInheritedGroup] [int] NOT NULL,
```

*: Cortei o restante do `CREATE TABLE` para dar brevidade no código.
**: Essas tabelas estão com um nome estranho, gostaria de alguma outra sugestão pra eles.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Explicação sobre a estrutura, a tabela de *Sistemas* e *Grupos* são obvias, porém, a tabela `InheritingSystem` e `InheritingGroup` são referentes as permissões herdadas das suas respectivas tabelas, portanto, o `IdSystem` e `IdGroup` são referentes ao *Sistema* e *Grupo*, respectivamente, que tem a permissão mais alta, e o `IdInheritedSystem` e `IdInheritedGroup` são os *Sistemas* e *Grupos*, respectivamente, que irão complementar a permissão.

Dados da tabela de Sistema:

[image: Dados da tabela de Sistema]

Dados da tabela de Grupo:

[image: Dados da tabela de Grupo]

Dados da tabela de Sistemas Herdados:

[image: Dados da tabela de Sistema Herdados]

Dados da tabela de Grupos Herdados:

[image: Dados da tabela de Grupos Herdados]

Comment: Posso estar bem enganado, mas sugestão de nomes geram respostas baseadas em opiniões

Comment: Não está, mas isso é apenas parte pequena da pergunta.

Comment: @Caffé, você poderia verificar se aparecem as imagens pra ti, por favor? Aqui elas não aparecem.

Comment: @Caffé, expliquei melhor a funcionalidade desta parte.

Comment: Acho que entendi. E onde entra o usuário nessa história? Será que a tabela dele é relevante nesta pergunta? Dá pra ter uma idéia do que você quer, mas não dá pra saber a solução que você tem até agora. Talvez você não escape de postar as 9 tabelas.

Comment: Então @Caffé, na verdade, não tenho interesse em sair dessas 9 tabelas, mesmo porque, até onde pesquisei, essa estrutura é a única estrutura que irá me atender nesse quesito e o usuário não é relevante para essa questão, pois minha dúvida roda em torno da construção das tabelas de `Herança` e seus relacionamentos, entende?

Comment: Ok. Tratando só do que temos aí, o que me parece é que você quer criar um grupo e adicionar a ele permissões de outros grupos já existentes; e o mesmo para os sistemas. Creio que esta linguagem seja mais simples e mais clara que "herança". Neste caso, as tabelas seriam: `GroupAddedGroups (Id, IdGroup, IdAddedGroup)` e `SystemAddedSystems (Id, IdSystem, IdAddedSystem)`. É claro que `Id` nestas tabelas está fazendo o papel se surrogate key e pode ser dispensado (depende de outras decisões de design). O que você acha?

Comment: @Caffé, transporta esse seu comentário para uma resposta, que eu vou marca-la como correta. Outra coisa, você tem alguma sugestão sobre a modelagem, tirando essas duas tabelas, no contexto geral, acha que está bom para o papel que irá desempenhar?

Comment: Teria que ver as outras tabelas. Existem muitas formas de definir permissões de usuários. Mas não vejo nada errado no que você fez até agora (tirando a nomenclatura que você já está melhorando). Talvez uma boa dica adicional seja: não planeje um sistema complexo de segurança que você não tenha certeza agora mesmo que você vai precisar. De saída, eu faria um sistema *hard coded* de grupos, cada usuário pertenceria a um grupo, e pronto. Se o cliente quiser mais flexibilidade no futuro, adicona-se mais flexibilidade **no futuro**.

Comment: @Caffé, entendo o que você quer dizer, mas no caso, já quero desenvolver algo complexo, e "completo" agora, para não ter que redesenvolver no futuro, visto que já sei que teria que aperfeiçoar o código. Mas obrigado pela ajuda! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tratando só do que temos aí, o que me parece é que você quer criar um grupo e adicionar a ele permissões de outros grupos já existentes; e o mesmo para sistemas.

Creio que esta linguagem ***"adicionar grupos a grupos"*** seja mais simples e mais clara que ***"herança"***.

Neste caso, as tabelas seriam:

- **GroupAddedGroups** (Id, IdGroup, IdAddedGroup)
- **SystemAddedSystems** (Id, IdSystem, IdAddedSystem)

É claro que Id nestas tabelas está fazendo o papel se surrogate key e pode ser dispensado (depende de outras decisões de design).

Answer (score 3):

`SystemInheritedPermissions` e `GroupInheritedPermissions` não acredito que seja um nome estranho, ou coloca em português mesmo.

Comment: Então, até gostei do nome, mas não usei `Permissions` em nenhuma outra tabela, nem as principais, como citado no código, então acho que sairia do padrão e em português vai sair do padrão, pois está todo em inglês.

Comment: Entendo, então, como vocês tem seus padrões, acredito que esta legal assim, ou muda de `InheritingSystem` para `SystemInheritances`, que ao invés de `herdar` ou `herdando`, ficará `heranças`, no caso `HerançasSistema`.

Comment: Eu acredito que vou colocar sua resposta como a correta, porém, ainda gostaria de uma opinião sobre a modelagem das permissões.

Comment: Seu código poderá ser visto e mantido por desenvolvedores de outro pais? por que em inglês? rsrs[Curiosidade]

Comment: @Rod, o inglês é apenas por convenção mesmo e porque como uso .NET, tudo é inglês, acabo mantendo todo o código em inglês para ficar consoante com a sintaxe. E não, o código é meu e não será mantido por estrangeiros, pelo menos não está nos meus planos isso, rs.

Comment: A grande maioria das linguagens são em inglês, ou todas, rs, uso .net também e não vejo problema em usar Português, desde que fique claro o que é a tabela/método ou o que for nomear, mas enfim...gosto é gosto, rsrs e nunca sabemos se não vai ser mantido  por estrangeiros kkk

Comment: @Rod, me expressei errado, rs... Apenas quis exemplificar o porque de estar em inglês. Então, pois é, a gringa está dominando o "resto do mundo", rs.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, dei meu quinhão sobre o assunto na resposta abaixo, veja se pode lhe atender.

[Quais as convenções de nomes na criação de base de dados, tabelas e colunas em mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6065/quais-as-conven%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-nomes-na-cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-base-de-dados-tabelas-e-colunas-em-m/279998#279998)